# Splitting pandas dataframe into multiple columns by row value

Tags: python, csv, pandas, split, dataframe

I am new to python and pandas and am attempting to make aggregate plots of orientation data across response time for my research. The approach I am attempting requires grouping and splitting the data by trial, however I have no index variable to group by in the raw data file. Just as some context, I am working with about 300 .csv files with 10-15k rows in each. Here is a snippet of the format of the raw .csv files:

```
   25.10          3.1         7.8       173.6       0.695646    -0.046507      0.716452 -0.024699       -0.014172   -0.712739   -0.086428   0.695940         88.4     1.8   -174.3  
   25.25          3.1         7.6       173.6       0.696440    -0.045587   0.715711    -0.025514       -0.013402   -0.712050   -0.085468   0.696778         88.5     1.7   -174.3  
   25.40          2.9         7.6       173.6       0.697160    -0.045407   0.715048    -0.024725       -0.014230   -0.711399   -0.085251   0.697454         88.6     1.7   -174.3  
   25.55          3.2         7.8       173.6       0.695360    -0.046466   0.716729    -0.024797       -0.014058   -0.713018   -0.086403   0.695660         88.4     1.8   -174.2  
    Response: S
    END TRIAL 1
    BEGIN TRIAL 2   
    0.05        126.4       126.4         0.0       -0.322306   -0.712941   -0.535465   -0.317978       -0.322306   -0.712941   -0.535465   -0.317978       105.7   -34.0    74.7   
    0.20        129.1       129.1         0.0       -0.311974   -0.711464   -0.555195   -0.297070       -0.311974   -0.711464   -0.555195   -0.297070       105.1   -37.2    76.3
```

As you can see there is no variable to group by trial or headers, only three rows (with a different structure) that separate the trials.

I have managed to get column headers and extract the relevant variables with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delim_whitespace=True, names=['time', 'S1', 'S2', 'Enc', 'q1a', 'q1b', 'q1c', 'q1d', 'q2a', 'q2b', 'q2c', 'q2d', 'yaw', 'pitch', 'roll'], header=0, usecols=['time', 'S1', 'S2'])
usecols=['time', 'S1', 'S2']
```

Which outputs this data structure:

```
    time    S1      S2
0   0.25    277.5   277.5
1   0.25    277.5   277.5
2   0.40    277.5   277.5
3   0.55    277.5   277.5
4   0.70    277.5   277.5
5   0.85    277.5   277.5
.........................
784 117.70  161.2   96.9
785 END     TRIAL   1.0
786 BEGIN   TRIAL   2.0
787 0.10    159.9   159.9
```

Closer, but now I am stuck on how to parse the individual trials into separate columns or data structures because there is no grouping list that signifies trial number and the number of rows varies for each trial. After reading through the Pandas documentation for the last few days and scouring similar questions raised here, I am having trouble finding the best solution.

Eventually, I'd like to have a single data structure to make some exploratory visualizations. Am I heading in the right direction, or is there a smarter approach to this?

Comment: Did you see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727386/split-pandas-dataframe-by-string? I would try splitting as in that question, then adding a trial-ID column, then (possibly) concatenating the split and identified dataframes into one frame to compare.

Comment: Awesome, I think that first answer got me on the right track. Dataframes are split properly now.